# Gembox spreedsheet excel file upload

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, gembox-spreadsheet

I want to read excel file using gembox like first row as header to check weather required column are present or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the reading example [here](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-open-read-excel-file/401).
Also, here is another example of how you can read just the first row:

```
var workbook = ExcelFile.Load("Sample.xlsx");
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
var firstRow = worksheet.Rows[0];

foreach (var cell in firstRow.AllocatedCells)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cell.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(cell.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("---");
}
```

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Another attempt to guess what exactly is requested here:

```
string[] expectedColumns = new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

var workbook = ExcelFile.Load("Sample.xlsx");
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
var firstRow = worksheet.Rows[0];

string[] actualColumns = firstRow.AllocatedCells
    .Select(cell => cell.Value != null ? cell.Value.ToString() : string.Empty)
    .ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < expectedColumns.Length; i++)
    if (expectedColumns[i] != actualColumns[i])
        throw new Exception("Unexpected column name detected!");
```

Note, `Select` and `ToArray`methods are provided by `System.Linq`.

Comment: thanks but i want to read first row as a header to check weather any clolum is missing or not

Comment: Apologize, but I don't know what you mean by "as a header", can you explain that a bit more? Note, all rows are read in the same way, as shown in my answer. Nevertheless, here is an update that I'm guessing could be of use to you.

Comment: as we are reading all rows, but i want to read first row of file as header(as like in data table) to check all the columns are present or not.